# Active item menu RoR

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

How I can get active item menu? Menu generate in cycle

```
<ul id="menu">  
  <% for page in Page.roots %>  
    <li><%= link_to h(page.name), page %></li>    
  <% end %>
  </ul>
```

I want use other css property for this item. 
Any ideas? Preferably js, jquery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's `link_to_unless_current` which wraps the link into an `a` tag unless the link is the current page (shows just the text without `a` tag). With some CSS tricks you can make that into different appearance. I usually use this approach:

```
<ul id="menu"><%= Page.roots.map do |page|
  content_tag :li, link_to_unless_current(h(page.name), page)
end %></ul>
```

and the following CSS:

```
ul#menu li { ...current/selected appearance... }
ul#menu li a { ...linked/normal appearance... }
```

Comment: For some more advanced designs you may want to look into `link_to_if` and `link_to_unless` or even wrap these into a helper.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#menu a[href$='+location.pathname+']").addClass('current');
```

The selector `#menu a` will find all links in your menu. `[href$='+location.pathname+']` this will find the link which ends with (`$=`) the same path as the current page, and than adds with `.addClass('current')` the css class `current`

Answer (score 0):

I tend to generate my own helper for this kind of thing:

```
#navigation_helper.rb
def nav_item(name, link, hilight = false)
  content_tag :li, link_to(name, link), :class => ("selected" if hilight)
end
```

Then in your views just pass a relevant boolean to the helper:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <%= nav_item "Foo admin", admin_path, (params[:controller] == "admin") %>
  <%= nav_item "Bar page", pages_path(@page), (params[:controller] == "pages" && params[:action] == "show" && params[:id] == @page.id) %>
  <%= nav_item "Baz example", example_path, any_old_helper? %>
</ul>
```

You'd need to think of a way of implementing this technique for your dynamically generated collection of pages, but where there's a will there's a way. :)